# How to sort a List of objects by the first key in a Treemap within the objects

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator, treemap

In my Java code I have a TranscriptionLog-class which looks like this:

```
class TranscriptionLog {

    private List<Sentence> sentenceList = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean isMerged;
```

The Sentence-class looks like this:

```
class Sentence {

private TreeMap<Long, WordObj> wordMap = new TreeMap<>();
private String sentence;
```

I want to sort the sentenceList by the key (long) of the first entry within it's  wordMap. I thought doing this in TranscriprionLog.java should work:

```
void sortSentenceList() {
    sentenceList.sort(Comparator.comparing(object -> object.getWordMap().firstEntry().getKey()));
}
```

-but it did not. It changed the order of the sentences but did not sort them correctly. Any thought on this?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Turned out this was an error earlier in the program. My sorting worked fine when that error was resolved.

Comment: Do you mind posting the results of your algorithm versus the original data

Comment: Normally I would, but the results are a bit hard to make sense of out of context. The goal is to be able to print a log of the sentences said, and the discussed sorting is done after merging to TranscriptionLogs. We know the correct order of the sentences as they are transcriped from an audio-file. The sorting changes the order but not correctly. The key in the treeMap is the millisecond the first word in the sentence is spoken. I will try to find a good way to demonstrate it. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: You can simplify the comparator to `Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getWordMap().firstKey())`. However, without code to reproduce the problem or a problem description more detailed than “did not sort them correctly”, there’s nothing we can do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I understand and will do that the next time I ask something.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're familiar with Java 8 Streams but something like this should work

```
//List initialized with results collected from the streaming operation
List<Sentence> result = sentenceList
                              .stream()
                              .sorted(
                                 (s1, s2) -> 
                                    s1.getWordMap().firstEntry().getKey()
                                    .compareTo(s2.getWordMap().firstEntry().getKey())
                              )
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the suggestion. I am not too familiar with Streams. Your suggestion gives a 'cannot resolve'-error on .collect() though:

Cannot resolve method 'collect(java.util.stream.Collector<T,capture<?>,java.util.List<T>>)'

Comment: Why do you think `(s1, s2) -> s1.getWordMap().firstEntry().getKey() .compareTo(s2.getWordMap().firstEntry().getKey()` was better than the OP’s `Comparator.comparing(object -> object.getWordMap().firstEntry().getKey())`? Besides that, there’s a `)` missing.

Comment: It turns out my sorting actually worked. The problem was that earlier in the program one of the sentences got a wrong key. But thank you both for your suggestions.

Comment: @Holger, oh thanks for the heads up, I'm not yet familiar with the `Comparator` class will have to take a look at it

Comment: @kristoffersylte That's awesome, hadn't come across the `Comparator` utility methods as well, so I guess we're all learning :). The problem is likely due to the missing bracket (the closing bracket for `sorted()`) @Holger was referring to in the comment; adding it should solve the problem